# How to get a count of checkboxes checked on pagination Jquery dataTables

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, datatables

Below is my code, I want to get the count of checked checkboxes of all pages in my DataTable. Please advice how to proceed

```
 <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" align="center" id="all" class="groupCheckBox" name="emails[]" value=' . $user['id'] . '></td>
```

Below code I used for get the values of checked boxes in all pages on button click

```
 $('#merge_button').click(function () {   
         var id = ""; 
         var oTable = $("#userTable").dataTable(); 
         $(".groupCheckBox:checked", oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function () { 

             if (id != "") { 
                 id = id + "," + $(this).val(); 
             } else { 
                 id = $(this).val(); 
             } 

             document.getElementById("email").value = id; 
         }); 
    });
```

but now I want to count the checkedboxes without button click function whenever user clicked on checkboxes and deduct count when unchecking boxes . pls advice

Comment: `$('[type="checkbox"].groupCheckBox:checked').length`

Comment: @Rayon : this doesn't count the checked items in other pages as well , I'm using Jquery datatables

Comment: Do they have different classes?

Comment: @Mihailo : I just update my question with the code I used for another pupose, it gives me the values onclick. but now I want to get the count when checked and unchecked without using onClick for button. pls advice

Comment: "The checkbox is not an `<input type="checkbox">` element, but rather a CSS that uses the :before and :after pseudo elements of the cell to draw a box and the tick."  from https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html - is this the pertinent reference?

Comment: If the _trigger_ is the problem then you could just change `$('#merge_button').click...` with `$('.groupCheckBox').click...`

Comment: @Mihailo : that was used to get the values, now I want to get the count of checked boxes  to show/hide the #merge_button . pls advice

Comment: set `#merge_button` to hidden (by default with `display:none`) and when when the count of checked checkboxes > 0 just do `$('#merge_button').show();`

Comment: @Mihailo : I'm struggling with get the count :( through pagination all pages., Please advice

Comment: Pagination changes your DOM, so you should "save" the count before changing the page, you could make a function that "saves" the count of checked checkboxes as a var each time that you change the page. But to help you any further I would need to personally look at the code, etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
var table = $("#userTable").DataTable();

var countchecked = table
    .rows()
    .nodes()
    .to$()      // Convert to a jQuery object
.find('input[type="checkbox"].groupCheckBox:checked').length;
```

Uses the most recent API

"...please be aware that using deferRender will cause some nodes to be created only when they are required for display, so they might not be immediately available when this method is called." from https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().nodes()

Comment: Still a Great Solution even after 8 years. you saved me

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy.

```
$("td input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
```

Comment: will  this not work with pagination, and when user checked and uncheked